# How to fix my bash script from error: syntax error near unexpected token `done'?

Tags: bash, unix, centos7, slurm

I am trying to run this bash program in a Centos7 machine.
I have tried many different ways but all the time I get this error:

> ```
> line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
> line 31: `done'
> ```

Line 31 belongs to the first `done`.

I did `cat -v mybash.bash` to check for weird tokens and there are none.

My script is as follows:

```
for mainFolder in *
do
    if [ -d "${mainFolder}" ]
    then
        cd "${mainFolder}" || exit
        echo "Entering in directory ${mainFolder}" 
        cp ../mypy.py .
        chmod +x mypy.py
        ./mypy.py
        echo "Executing mypy.py"
        sleep 1

        for subFolder in *
        do
            if [ -d "${subFolder}" ]
            then
                cd "${subFolder}" || exit
                echo "Entering in directory $subFolder in $mainFolder"
                echo "Submitting slurm file in current directory"
                sbatch *.slurm
                sleep 1
            fi
            cd ..
        done
    fi
    cd ..
done
```

Please help me notice what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. Your `if` statements are wrong, you need spaces around `[` and `]`. And you should quote all your variables in case they contain spaces.

Comment: Paste your script into shellcheck.net to see all the other problems.

Comment: Which line is line 31? You only posted 27 lines. Is there more that you haven't shown?

Comment: yeah. This is originally a slurm submission file. I am not c/p the #SBATCH parts.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Slurm, maybe the problem is due to the way it executes it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way you're using `done` in the script. Try fixing all your other errors, see if that's still a problem.

Comment: even if I do it a bash file it does not run

Comment: I just realized now that it does not enter to the first if statement

Comment: Did you fix the other errors I mentioned?

Comment: yes. I updated the code

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning so you can see the statements as they're executed.

Comment: You need to put the *last* `cd ..` inside the if statement.

Comment: I guess the problem is that `*.slurm` returns nothing, because there is no such file.
Apart from that, several problems as mentioned in other comments. About the `cd ..`, they should probably both be in the end of the `then` blocks, i.e. executed only when preceded by a `cd`.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the slurm submission script is not there. The following checks that one and no more than one script is found.

I also moved the `cd ..` to happen only after a `cd`.

```sh
for mainFolder in *
do
    if [ -d "${mainFolder}" ]
    then
        echo "Entering in directory ${mainFolder}" 
        cd "${mainFolder}" || exit
        cp ../mypy.py .
        chmod +x mypy.py
        echo "Executing mypy.py"
        ./mypy.py
        sleep 1

        for subFolder in *
        do
            if [ -d "${subFolder}" ]
            then
                cd "${subFolder}" || exit
                echo "Entering in directory $subFolder in $mainFolder"
                scripts=$(ls *.slurm)
                nScripts=$(echo $scripts | wc -w)
                if [ $nScripts == 1 ]
                then
                    echo "Submitting $scripts"
                    sbatch $scripts
                elif [ $nScripts == 0 ]
                then
                    echo "Error: No script found"
                else
                    echo "Error: $nScripts scripts found (${scripts})"
                fi
                sleep 1
                cd ..
            fi
        done
        cd ..
    fi
done
```